# Crystal report using visual studio gives wrong value like color names,day names etc

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, crystal-reports

I want to create a crystal report using visual studio 2010.I have linked my ms-access database with visual studio c# web application. I have gone through some tutorials for crystal report download and usage.

Ms-access Table:customer_vcs(ID,cname,contact,email,address).

Now this table have below mentioned data.

[image: Ms-access table values in visual studio]

But when i previewed the crystal report from customer_vcs table,it show the below mentioned values:

[image: Crystal Report values of the above said ms-access table]

Now i dont understand from where these data of crystal report came.
Please help me.

Comment: give us some code and more specification info. What data do you send to CR, and where is the mismatch or the error, because your screenshots show different records

Comment: @jambonick this is exactly my query,i want to generate the crystal report from customer_vcs table,but it shows different value....I dont know from the CR values came... Please help

Comment: How have you linked your data to crystal report? Don't you have a SQL query or some c# code? Have you done it with Report Wizard maybe?

Comment: @jambonick using report wizard.

Comment: is there any other table in your database which contains the data displayed in your report? Maybe you have made an error during creating the connection through the wizard. Also can you show us a) a screen shot of your Database -> Database Expert menu in order to see the connection and b) a screenshot of your Database -> Show SQL Query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey @jambonick i found the problem somehow accidently.For creating crystal report i must select the DSN name which i need to create from ms-access database.Simple ms-access database connection will not take any effect for crystal report generation.